# Unable to resolve COM reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, com, vb6

I am facing problem while resolving COM reference in Visual studio 2010.Here is whats happening,

1. I have `vb6` project which outputs a .dll. I want to use this dll in VS2010 project. Currently I am trying to do that by registering dll using `regsvr32` and consuming in .net as COM object
2. When I add reference by selecting COM object on COM Tab, reference get resolved and I am able to build the project.
3. But if I compile the vb6 project again, VS2010 project build fails saying unable to resolve COM reference.

How to resolve this?

Comment: VB6 aggressively makes a COM component incompatible when you make changes.  Which forces you to re-import it so .NET knows the new guids and the added/changed members.  Select binary compatibility in your VB6 project to avoid this.  Design first, program later is the wise advice.

Comment: Nothing "aggressive" about it really.  It is pretty rare for this to occur unless you have made an egregious change which requires a compatibility break to avoid a run time failure.  Type libraries are contracts.